# An urn containing numbered balls probability

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn containing numbered balls 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively. Two balls are selected, one at a time and at random of the casket. Let X be a va denoting the sum of the numbers of the selected balls.
Guys, how can I get the probability distribution, the expected value, variance and standard deviation of X for example?

Comment: I will assume it is without replacement. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose $2$ balls. One of these gives sum $3$. So $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{1}{6}$. One gives sum $4$. Two give sum $5$. Continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a simple grid, we have the probability of all 5 possible results

$\begin{array}{c|cccc} \sum & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline 1 & ~ & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 & ~ & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 & ~ & 7 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &~\end{array}$

So $\mathsf P(X=x)= \begin{cases}\boxed{?} & : x\in \{3,4,6,7\} \\ \boxed{?} & : x=5 \\ 0 & :\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

From this find $\mathsf E(X) = \boxed{?}\cdot(3+4+6+7)+\boxed{?}\cdot 5$

Likewise you can find $\mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))^2)$

Comment: is your defn of Var right - Wikipedia says different https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Graham just has a typo. He has forgotten the right part of the second bracket.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.